# Convert IList<Object> to a List<String>

Tags: vb.net, winforms, list, ilist

I have a list (returned from database) and I have a combo box which I am populating with a list, I am doing this because the `ComboBox` can be populated from a range of data sources.

I need to convert the `IList(Of Object)` into a `List(Of String)`.

The `Object` has an override on the `ToString` method.

Please can anyone advise on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `IList(Of Object)`, like this:

```
Dim objects As IList(Of Object) = New List(Of Object)({"test", "test2"})
```

You can add the items in that list to a `ComboBox`, directly, like this:

```
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(objects.ToArray())
```

There is no need to first convert it to a `List(Of String)` since the `ComboBox` automatically calls the `ToString` method for you on each item in the list.  However, if you really need to convert it to a `List(Of String)`, you can do it like this:

```
Dim strings As List(Of String) = objects.Select(Function(x) x.ToString()).ToList()
```

Or, if you don't want to use the LINQ extension methods, you could do it the old-fashioned way, like this:

```
Dim strings As New List(Of String)()
For Each i As Object In objects
    strings.Add(i.ToString())
Next
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I need to pass to a list of string prior to populating, because the Combo Box can be populated from database objects, or the results of a web call.

Comment: Oops, for some reason I thought you said `ListBox`.  I updated my answer for the `ComboBox`.  The same principles apply.  Did this solution work for you, or did you still have a question?

Answer (score 1):

Use linq:

```
    Private Function ConvertToListOfString(lstObject As IList(Of Object)) As List(Of String)
        Return lstObject.Select(Function(e) e.ToString()).ToList()
    End Function
```